# Compose a large list of links using different variables

Tags: r

I need to compose a link list using time dependent variables. Until now I've managed to work with `paste()` but the results are unsatisfactory. The links follow this structure:

```
http://www.somesite/year/month/day/hour/minute.txt
```

I've tried to create a variable for each part.

```
link <-'http://www.somesite'

year<-as.character(c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"))
month<-as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"))
day<-as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12",
                    "13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24",
                    "25","26","27","28","29","30","31"))
hour<-as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12",
                     "13","14","15","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23",
                     "24"))
min <-as.character(c("00","10","20","30","40","50"))
ext <-as.character("ext")
```

Using `paste()`:

```
link2 <-paste(link,year,"/",month,"/",day,"/",hour,"/",minute,".",ext)
```

I get this:

```
  [1]"http:/somesite/2010/01/01/01/10.ext"
    [2]"http:/somesite/2011/02/02/02/20.ext"
    [3]"http:/somesite/2012/03/03/03/30.ext"
    [4]"http:/somesite/2013/04/04/04/40.ext"
    ****************************************
```

I want to get something like this:

```
 [1]"http:/somesite/2010/01/01/01/10.ext"
    [2]"http:/somesite/2010/02/01/01/20.ext"
    [3]"http:/somesite/2010/03/01/01/30.ext"
    [4]"http:/somesite/2010/04/01/01/40.ext"
    ****************************************
```

Any ideas? I don't want to enter it manually. :)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood your question. The expected output is entered in the way that I want it,  not the paste() output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand.grid` could get you started...

```
dat  <- list(link  = 'http://www.somesite',
             year = as.character(c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014")),
             month = as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")),
             day = as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12",
                    "13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24",
                    "25","26","27","28","29","30","31")),
             hour = as.character(c("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12",
                     "13","14","15","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23",
                     "24")),
             min  = as.character(c("00","10","20","30","40","50")),
             ext  = as.character("ext"))

gr <- expand.grid(dat)

# sort results...
gr <- gr[order(gr$year, gr$month, gr$day, gr$hour, gr$min),]

head(gr)

#                       link year month day hour min ext
# 1      http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  00 ext
# 46501  http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  10 ext
# 93001  http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  20 ext
# 139501 http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  30 ext
# 186001 http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  40 ext
# 232501 http://www.somesite 2010    01  01   01  50 ext
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to name all the column names if you want to order by *all* the columns, just do `gr <- gr[do.call(order, gr), ]`